# Read input from user and ignore the spaces between words, converting letters to telephone numbers

Tags: java, if-statement

I've been trying to figure out how to ignore the blank space/digits/letters by using the character.isDigit & character.isLetter method when the users enters a String.. Can you guys please advise me?

When I tried the input with GETLOAN (Without the space) it works well... 
But when I enter a space between e..g. Get Loan, the program shows an error..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String letters;
    char phoneDigit;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter letters : ");
    letters = kb.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        phoneDigit = letters.charAt(i);

        // Using character.isDigit...
        if (Character.isDigit(phoneDigit) == true || Character.isLetter(phoneDigit) == true);
        {

            if (i == 3) {
                System.out.println("-");
            } //If 

            if (phoneDigit >= 'A' && phoneDigit <= 'C'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'a' && phoneDigit <= 'c') {

                System.out.println("2");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'D' && phoneDigit <= 'F'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'd' && phoneDigit <= 'f') {

                System.out.println("3");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'G' && phoneDigit <= 'I'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'g' && phoneDigit <= 'i') {

                System.out.println("4");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'J' && phoneDigit <= 'L'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'j' && phoneDigit <= 'l') {

                System.out.println("5");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'M' && phoneDigit <= 'O'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'm' && phoneDigit <= 'o') {

                System.out.println("6");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'P' && phoneDigit <= 'S'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'p' && phoneDigit <= 's') {

                System.out.println("7");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'T' && phoneDigit <= 'V'
                    || phoneDigit >= 't' && phoneDigit <= 'v') {

                System.out.println("8");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'W' && phoneDigit <= 'Z'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'W' && phoneDigit <= 'z') {

                System.out.println("9");
            } // If
        } // If
    } // For loop

} //PSVM
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: Hi guys I received "String index out of range: 3" from the IDE... Is there any possible way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

remove the semicolon(;) from here

```
if (Character.isDigit(phoneDigit) == true || Character.isLetter(phoneDigit) == true);//semicolon
```

`;` means end of statement.This means `if` conditions ended there.The statements under `if` will always be executed irrespective of what `if` returns(true or false) so the rest of statements under `{}` will simply behave as non static blocks

*When I tried the input with GETLOAN (Without the space) it works well... But when I enter a space between e..g. Get Loan, the program shows an error..*

You are getting error when you enter space because of the reason I specified above as the statements under `if` will always be executed

Comment: You get a StringIndexOutOfBounds exception irrespective of whether you remove the semicolon or not. This is because the Scanner splits the inpout by space.

Comment: @SamuelRenold if ; is there then dont you think {} will always be executed?

Comment: @SamuelRenold generally we do not run codes in our machines and just do an overlook of the bunches of code posted. I came up with that problem and posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter two words separated by a space, e.g. "get loan", the Scanner produces two output elements, i.e. the invocation of `kb.next()` just returns "get". A second invocation would return "loan". The Scanner class is not the right class to use for your purpose.
Use something like

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter String");
String s = br.readLine();
```

to read from the console.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Samuel! Is there any ways to ignore the blank spaces, digits and letters?

Comment: You can override the scanner's default delimiter using useDelimiter(...) from the Scanner class. Please remember, the purpose of the Scanner class is string tokenisation.

Comment: A very simple way of removing spaces from a string is `letter = letter.replace(" ", "");`